# C, OS independent way to write uncompressed avi files

Tags: library, video, c

I am working at a program that will convert camera raw files into movies, for example stop motion or time lapse stuff. The program is written in C using SDL and a few other libs so that it can run on any platform. Now I would like to find a way to turn the images into a video.

One obvious way is libx264, but it's GPL and I am not sure I want to release my program as GPL. Ideally I would output to some uncompressed format, then the user can run the AVI into their own video editor to add music, subtitles, other effects, etc. Or they can use Handbrake to compress it to their desired format.

So is there any good, open source, multi platform library that can output some widely used video format, preferably directly from RGB space?